# Combine data frame rows in R based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I have a data frame in R which has one individual per line. Sometimes, individuals appear on two lines, and I would like to combine these lines based on the duplicated ID.

The problem is, each individual has multiple IDs, and when an ID appears twice, **it does not necessarily appear in the same column**.

Here is an example data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c('cat', 'canine', 'feline', 'dog'),
                  b = c('feline', 'puppy', 'meower', 'wolf'),
                  c = c('kitten', 'barker', 'kitty', 'canine'),
                  d = c('shorthair', 'collie', '', ''),
                  e = c(1, 5, 3, 8))

> dat
       a      b      c         d e
1    cat feline kitten shorthair 1
2 canine  puppy barker    collie 5
3 feline meower  kitty           3
4    dog   wolf canine           8
```

So rows 1 and 3 should be combined, because ID `b` of row 1 equals ID `a` of row 3. Similarly, ID `a` of row 2 equals ID `c` of row 4, so those rows should be combined as well.

Ideally, the output should look like this.

```
     a.1    b.1    c.1       d.1 e.1    a.2    b.3    c.2 d.2 e.2
1    cat feline kitten shorthair   1 feline meower  kitty       3
2 canine  puppy barker    collie   5    dog   wolf canine       8
```

(Note that the rows were not combined based on sharing IDs that are empty strings.)

**My thoughts on how this could be done are below, but I'm pretty sure that I've been headed down the wrong path, so they're probably not helpful in solving the problem.**

I thought that I could assign a row ID to each row, then melt the data. After that, I could to through row by row. When I found a row where one of the IDs matched an earlier row (e.g. when one of the row 3 IDs matches one of the row 1 IDs), I would change the every instance of the current row's row ID to match the earlier row ID (e.g. all row IDs of 3 would be changed to 1).

Here's the code I've been using:

```
dat$row.id <- 1:nrow(dat)
library(reshape2)
dat.melt <- melt(dat, id.vars = c('e', 'row.id'))
for (i in 2:nrow(dat.melt)) {
  # This next step is just to ignore the empty values
  if (grepl('^[[:space:]]*$', dat.melt$value[i])) {
    next
  }
  earlier.instance <- dat.melt$row.id[which(dat.melt$value[1:(i-1)] == dat.melt$value[i])]
  if (length(earlier.instance) > 0) {
    earlier.row.id <- earlier.instance[1]
    dat.melt$row.id[dat.melt$row.id == dat.melt$row.id[i]] <- earlier.row.id
  }
}
```

There are two problems with this approach.

1. It could be that an ID in row 3 matches row 1, and a different ID in row 5 matches row 3. In this case, the row IDs for both row 3 and row 5 should be changed to 1. This means that it's important to go through the rows sequentially, which has been leading me to use a for loop, not an apply function. I know that this is not very R-like, and with the large data frame I am working with it is very slow.
2. This code produces the output below. There are now multiple rows with identical `row.id` and `variable`, so I don't know how to cast it in order to get the kind of output I showed above. Using `dcast` here will be forced to use an aggregation function.

Output:

```
   e row.id variable     value
1  1      3        a       cat
2  5      2        a    canine
3  3      3        a    feline
4  8      2        a       dog
5  1      3        b    feline
6  5      2        b     puppy
7  3      3        b    meower
8  8      2        b      wolf
9  1      3        c    kitten
10 5      2        c    barker
11 3      3        c     kitty
12 8      2        c    canine
13 1      3        d shorthair
14 5      2        d    collie
15 3      3        d          
16 8      2        d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer. Had some fun (/frustration) working through this. I'm sure it is not the fastest solution but it should get you past where my other answer left off. Let me explain:

```
dat <- data.table(a = c('cat', 'canine', 'feline', 'dog', 'cat','fido'),
                  b = c('feline', 'puppy', 'meower', 'wolf', 'kitten', 'dog'),
                  c = c('kit', 'barker', 'kitty', 'canine', 'feline','wolf'),
                  d = c('shorthair', 'collie', '', '','',''),
                  e = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

dat[, All := paste(a, b,c),]
```

Two changes: `dat$e` is now an index column, so it is just the numeric position of whichever row it is. If `e` is otherwise important, you can make a new column to replace it.

Below is the first loop. This makes 3 new columns `FirstMatchingID` etc. These are like before: they give the index of the earliest (lowest row #) matching `dat$All` for `a` `b` and `c`.

```
for(i in 2:nrow(dat)) {
  x <- grepl(dat[i]$a, dat[i-(1:i)]$All)
  y <- max(which(x %in% TRUE))
  dat[i, FirstMatchingID := dat[i-y]$e]

  x2 <- grepl(dat[i]$b, dat[i-(1:i)]$All)
  y2 <- max(which(x2 %in% TRUE))
  dat[i, SecondMatchingID := dat[i-y2]$e]

  x3 <- grepl(dat[i]$c, dat[i-(1:i)]$All)
  y3 <- max(which(x3 %in% TRUE))
  dat[i, ThirdMatchingID := dat[i-y3]$e]

}
```

Next, we use `pmin` to find the earliest matching row of the `MatchingID` columns and set it in its own columns. This is in case you have a match `a` in row 25 and a match for `b` in row 12; it will give you 12 (I assume this is what you'd want based on your question).

```
dat$MinID <- pmin(dat$FirstMatchingID, dat$SecondMatchingID, dat$ThirdMatchingID, na.rm=T)
```

Last, this loop will do 3 things, creating a `FinalID` column with all the matching ID numbers from `e`:

1. Where `MinID` is `NA` (no matches) set `FinalID` to `e`
2. If `MinID` is a number, find that row (the earliest match) and check if *its* `MinID` is a number; if it is not, there are no earlier matches and it sets `FinalID` to `MinID`
3. The rows that don't fit the above condition are your special cases where row `i`s earliest match has an earlier match itself. This will find that match and set it to `FinalID`.

`for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
      x <- dat[i]$MinID
      if (is.na(dat[i]$MinID)) {
        dat[i, FinalID := e]
      } else if (is.na(dat[x]$MinID)) {
        dat[i, FinalID := MinID]
      } else dat[i, FinalID := dat[x]$MinID]
    }`

I think this should do it; let me know how it goes. I make no claims about its efficiency or speed.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. I had been seeking a vectorized solution, believing that this would be faster, but after reading part of _The R Inferno_, I learned that this is not necessarily the case. I have a couple questions. 1) Why did you use `grepl` and then `max` to get the maximum index instead of just using `max(grep(...))`? 2) When you write `dat[i]$MinID`, do you mean to write `dat$MinID[i]`? Those work differently for me. I haven't tried your exact code, because I'm just adapting the ideas for my real data, so I can't speak to the accuracy of the syntax, but the ideas seem solid.

Comment: Let's see. 1) `x<- grepl(...` returns a vector of T/F for match/no match, then `which(x %in% TRUE)`  gives the position of the T/F elements that are true (meaning there was a match), then `max` gets the match closest to the top of the data.table (or furthest from current row i). 2) I meant to write it that way. Try my full code out, it works for me as is and not when I change it, but you can check yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I how that `grepl` then `which` works, I was just wondering if there was a specific reason you were creating a T/F vector and then pulling indices from it instead of getting the indices directly with `grep`. I guess either way is good.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right. The specific reason was that I did not know that, it would seem.

Comment: Well, I guess we both learned something! Mostly me though; I didn't even know about data.table!

Comment: I'm a big fan of data.table over dplyr, personally (if you know about dplyr). The syntax is much more compact and I haven't found that I need to resort to dplyr for any functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an amateur attempt. I think it does some of what you want. I have expanded the data.frame (now a data.table) two rows to give a better example.

This loop creates a new column, `dat$FirstMatchingID`, that contains the ID from `dat$e` for the earliest match. I've only done it to match the first column, `dat$a`, but I think it could be expanded to `b` and `c` easily enough.

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(a = c('cat', 'canine', 'feline', 'dog', 'feline','puppy'),
                  b = c('feline', 'puppy', 'meower', 'wolf', 'kitten', 'dog'),
                  c = c('kitten', 'barker', 'kitty', 'canine', 'cat','wolf'),
                  d = c('shorthair', 'collie', '', '','',''),
                  e = c(1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 6))

dat[, All := paste(a, b,c),]

for(i in 2:nrow(dat)) {
  print(dat[i])
  x <- grepl(dat[i]$a, dat[i-(1:i)]$All)
  y <- max(which(x %in% TRUE))
  dat[i, FirstMatchingID := dat[i-y]$e]
}
```

The result:

```
        a      b      c         d e                 All FirstMatchingID
1:    cat feline kitten shorthair 1   cat feline kitten              NA
2: canine  puppy barker    collie 5 canine puppy barker              NA
3: feline meower  kitty           3 feline meower kitty               1
4:    dog   wolf canine           8     dog wolf canine              NA
5: feline kitten    cat           4   feline kitten cat               1
6:  puppy    dog   wolf           6      puppy dog wolf               5
```

You then have to find out how you want to combine the rows to get your desired result, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: This is an extremely helpful suggestion, and I've already started playing around with it. Right now I'm looking for ways to 1) replace the loop, since I have a huge dataset and looping is slow, and 2) make all instances point to the first line in their "network" of names. For example, say that row six was `fido dog wolf`. Then FirstMatchingID for row six would be 4. But because row six would be connected to row two _via row four_, I would want FirstMatchingID to be 2. If you can figure out a way around these problems, it would turn an already very helpful answer into an amazing one. Thanks!